# Tooltip only showing in top in Bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

Hi I'm working in Laravel 7 with the Currently v5.1.3  Bootstrap... I'm using the bootstrap.bunble.min.js file. Calling the tooltip function via the data-bs-toggle attribute:

```
    <span class="badge-sale"
    data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
    title="Ends in 3 hours from now">
    Sale!</span>
```

and the initializator of tooltip in my js file:

```
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
})
```

ONLY in the top of the web tooltip is displayed correctly but when I scroll further down it is no longer displayed.

[image]

Comment: Try to create a reproducible example so the community has access to help you directly over the cause of this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap's .container-fluid class has been used, so this is passed as a container parameter when initialising Tooltip, modifying it would look like this:

```
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl,{
    container: '.container-fluid'
 });
});
```